# Making GridView with Fragment Instances

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I want to implement GridView that each cell contains an object of class. for this I implemented fragment class:

```
public class DayUC extends Fragment {

    /*
    some variables
    */

    // use to create instance of class with initial parameters
    public static DayUC newInstance(//initial parameters) {
        DayUC dayUC = new DayUC();
        /*
        set parameters
        */
        return dayUC;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        initialization()       //initial variables and view elemans (textView, ...)
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and also I created GridViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<DayUC> gridList;      //list of grid DayUC objects
    Context context;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DayUC> gridList) {
        this.gridList = gridList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gridList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DayUC getItem(int position) {
        return gridList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return gridList.get(position).getView();
    }
}
```

but when I create GridView it throws NullPointerException! I found that in gridView elements (DayUC) **onCreateView()** never called. so **gridList.get(position).getView()** returns null!!

could anyone help me to solve this problem? how could I force **onCreateView** to be called??

**Edit: MainActivity onCreate method added**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DayUC[] dayUC = new DayUC[42];

        monthGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.month_view);

        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            dayUC[i] = DayUC.newInstance(//inpute arguments)
            dayUCList.add(dayUC[i]);
            monthCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        gridViewAdapter = new MonthGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), dayUCList);
        monthGridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
        gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: where you are intializing ArrayList<DayUC> gridList?

Comment: Why storing `DayUC` Fragment objects in ArrayList<DayUC>?

Comment: In OnCreateView add gridview (rootview.findviewbyid(gridviewid) and set the adapter or add  initialization() method so find proper bug

Comment: your code is completely wrong, you need read `GridView` and `Fragment` documentation to move in right way.

Comment: @Nag: in my main aactivity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : because I want to show **DayUC** objects in gridView

Comment: @shayan pourvatan: could you tell me how should I do that? or give me some example code?

Comment: what you want to do? you want to show witch object? as i see your code you create one list as fragment class, what is main object? you need create custom class and set your property and show in grid Item.

Comment: @shayan pourvatan: I want to show grid of DayUC objects! so I created a ArrayList of DayUC and passed it to my custom adapter.
MainActivity codes added

Comment: I don't think it's right way, create one custom class with witch property that you want then create your view in `getView` and set your data to that, see http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/ for more info

Comment: @shayan pourvatan: I want to use my Fragment view not creating custom view again!! is there any way to using my custom fragment object (DayUC) view in grid view?? because when I want to return dayUC.getView it causes NullPointerException!!